# How to get value at particular index from a vector?

Tags: java, vector

When I return vector data using elementAt(2), I am getting this output.

```
Hello [162, Experiment 3.doc, E:\Desktop\Experiment 3.doc, doc, 35.5 kb]
```

I want the index value: "Experiment 3.doc".

```
// Function to fetch data from Database and store in jtable
public Vector getEmployee(String searchQuery)throws Exception
{
    Connection con = null;
    try{
        Class.forName(driver); 
    } catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        Vector<Vector<String>> employeeVector = new Vector<>();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"conjure","conjure");

        String query = "SELECT * FROM APP.FILES WHERE NAME LIKE '%"+searchQuery+"%'";
        Statement st = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()) {
            Vector<String> file = new Vector<>();
            file.add(rs.getString(1)); //Empid
            file.add(rs.getString(2)); //name
            file.add(rs.getString(3)); //position
            file.add(rs.getString(4)); //externsion
            file.add(rs.getString(5)); //size
            employeeVector.add(file);
        }
        rs.close();
        return employeeVector;
        } catch (Throwable err) {
           err.printStackTrace();
           System.out.println("Inside two");
        } finally {
        con.close();
    }
    return null;
}

// Button click, show data in jtable.
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{ 
    String searchQuery = jTextField1.getText();
    //get data from database
    DBEngine dbengine = new DBEngine();
    try {
        data = dbengine.getEmployee(searchQuery);
        System.out.println("Hello "+data.elementAt(2));
        jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data,header));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now I want to use column 3, i.e. filename (Experiment 3.doc) somewhere else. 
How can I do that?

Comment: What is the object type that the `Vector` contains?

Comment: It seems that vector is returning something at index 2.

Comment: could you post the code you are running for the enlightenment of everyone. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a `Vector` of `Vector`s.

`data.elementAt(2)` will return a `Vector` of `String`s.  You then need to get the next element from this resulting `Vector`, presumably `data.elementAt(2).getElementAt(2)`